# Simple Red5 - WebRTC connector

Tags: webrtc, adapter, rtsp, red5

I am using red5 server -open source not pro-. And it is currently gives RTSP end-point (like rtsp://x.x.x.x:pppp/live/abc). It doesn't support webRTC. Is it possible to create an adapter for open source red5 media server to connect webRTC ? If yes what steps can I follow ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course its possible; at a high level that's what we did with Red5 Pro, we created a WebRTC plugin in the same style as the RTSP plugin.